# Sharepoint 2010: Programmatically access a documents metadata via a link

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Is it possible to (in code) access the metadata of a document stored in a library via a link to that document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get SPFile object using the SPWeb.GetFile method, then use the Item property of that object to get access to the ListItem accompanying the file.

```
using(SPSite site = new SPSite(link))
{
  using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
  {
   SPFile file = web.GetFile(link);
   SPListItem item = file.Item;

   object fieldValue = item["some field"];
  }
}
```

Comment: Finally got round to using this. Works!